# Selenium having issues selecting radio buttons in python

Tags: python, selenium, button, radio-button, web-crawler

I'm trying to select from a set of radio buttons of unknown size. (multiple sets, but one step at a time..) On the actual site they won't be text1 for values. The form id is randomly generated, but follows a pattern. So I can't really use it. I get a consistent class..

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("new_question")
mine = element.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.my_answer")
r1 = self.pickRandom(len(mine)) # gets a random number in the range
```

I've tried just adding `.click()` to the end, nothing happens. 
    `element.find_elements_by_css_selector("input.my_answer")[0].click()`

```
<form id="a_1028" class="answer_area" name="a_1028" >
<label>
<input class="my_answer" type="radio" onclick="Process.checkForm('1028')" value="1" name="my_answer" >
text1
</label>
<label>
<input class="my_answer" type="radio" onclick="Process.checkForm('1028')" value="2" name="my_answer" ">
text2
</label>
<label>
<input class="my_answer" type="radio" onclick="Process.checkForm('1028')" value="3" name="my_answer" >
text3
</label>
<label>
<input class="my_answer" type="radio" onclick="Process.checkForm('1028')" value="4" name="my_answer" >
text4
</label>
<p>Check Boxes…</p>
<label>
<input class="their_answer" type="checkbox" onclick="Process.checkBox('1028')" value="1"     name="their_answer" >
CB1
</label>
<label>
<input class="their_answer" type="checkbox" onclick="Process.checkBox('1028')" value="2"     name="their_answer" >
CB2
</label>
<label>
<input class="their_answer" type="checkbox" onclick="Process.checkBox('1028')" value="3" name="their_answer" >
CB3
</label>
<label>
<input class="their_answer" type="checkbox" onclick="Process.checkBox('1028')" value="4"     name="their_answer">
CB4
</label>
```

Comment: Are any errors and/or exceptions thrown?

Comment: Nope nothing happens. I think it has to do with the javascript call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to the chrome version, and it worked. Guess the selenium guys have a major bug in their firefox driver.